# How to expand navigation properties on POST/PUT OData request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using OData ASP.NET Core 7.4.1

For exemple, with a request `GET https://localhost:44346/api/v1/estates/74EEAB44-B8E7-EA11-B361-D43B04C15376?$expand=tenants` , I can get a entity with the info of `tenants`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44346/odata/v1/$metadata#Estates(tenants(),tenants())",
    "value": [
        {            
            "updatedOn": "2020-08-26T16:22:01.03+02:00",
            "tenants": [
                {
                    "name": "tenant"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But with Put request `PUT https://localhost:44346/odata/v1/estates(74EEAB44-B8E7-EA11-B361-D43B04C15376)?$expand=tenants` , I can get my returned entity but without `tenants`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44346/odata/v1/$metadata#Estates(tenants(),tenants())",
    "value": [
        {            
            "updatedOn": "2020-08-26T16:22:01.03+02:00",
            "tenants": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Question : How to return `tenants` of returned entity in `PUT` request, because I don't want to have to make a `GET(id)` call to the server to refresh a created/updated entity. The server should return exactly the same representation of the entity as the `GET(id)`.

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1675) opened about this but not resolve. Someone has solved this problem ?

Comment: Hi, @Antoine V, **HttpPut** works on my Odata. Could u share your method of HTTP PUT?

Comment: Yes, you need to share your controller method that processes PUT, the response mechanism that you use from that method determines how and if the response is serialized with the `tenants` navigation data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the setting in Startup.cs

```
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(10).Count();

            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);
            builder.EntitySet<Tenants>("estates");
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata/v1", builder.GetEdmModel());
        });
```

Codes of Modes

```
public class Tenants
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedOn { get; set; }
    public List<Tenant> tenants { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

### HTTP GET

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var tenants = (await dataProvider.GetTenants()).ToList();
        return Ok(tenants);
    }
```

[image]

### HTTP PUT

```
    [HttpPut("{key}")]
    [ODataRoute("{key}")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ([FromODataUri] Guid key, [FromBody] Estate estate)
    {
        var tenants = (await dataProvider.SetTenants(name)).ToList();
        return Ok(tenants);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your post but your idea help me to make the code work